# c++: Use templates to wrap any lambda inside another lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I want to make a function that can wrap any lambda to log start/end calls on it.

The code below works except for:

1. any lambda that has captures
2. any lambda that returns void (although this can easily be fixed by writing a second function)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <class T, class... Inputs>
auto logLambda(T lambda) {
    return [&lambda](Inputs...inputs) {
        std::cout << "STARTING " << std::endl;
        auto result = lambda(inputs...);
        std::cout << "END " << std::endl;
        return result;
    };
}

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    // works
    auto simple = []() -> int {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl; return 1;
    };
    logLambda(simple)();

    // works so long as explicit type is declared
    auto with_args = [](int a, int b) -> int {
        std::cout << "A: " << a << " B: " << b << std::endl;
        return 1;
    };
    logLambda<int(int, int), int, int>(with_args)(a, b);

    // Does not work
    // error: no matching function for call to ‘logLambda<int(int), int>(main()::<lambda(int)>&)’
    auto with_captures = [&a](int b) -> int {
        std::cout << "A: " << a << " B: " << b << std::endl;
        return 1;
    };
    logLambda<int(int), int>(with_captures)(b);

}
```

Is there any way to do this? Macros are also acceptable

Comment: you get an error for the code? Please include it in the question

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent `std::function`?

Comment: Your code has UB. You capture the function-local variable `lambda` by reference and return that. Capture by value instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Raii to handle both void and non-void return type,
and capture functor by value to avoid dangling reference,
and use generic lambda to avoid to have to specify argument your self

It results something like:

```
template <class F>
auto logLambda(F f) {
    return [f](auto... args) -> decltype(f(args...)) {
        struct RAII {
            RAII()  { std::cout << "STARTING " << std::endl; }
            ~RAII() { std::cout << "END " << std::endl; }
        } raii;

        return f(args...);
    };
}
```

Call look like:

```
const char* hello = "Hello";
logLambda([=](const char* s){ std::cout << hello << " " << s << std::endl; })("world");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a707c8388ac6a84a)

Comment: Does it make sense to do forwarding references? E.g. `auto logLambda(F&& f)` and `return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);`

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. I omit it as verbose and OP don't use it originally.

Answer (score 3):

That code has undefined behavior.

```
auto logLambda(T lambda) {
    return [&lambda]
```

You are capturing local parameter by reference.

Comment: what is wrong with capturing by reference? Isn't that the point of lambdas?

Comment: @mdsimmo Please read the entire statement: "You are capturing **local parameter** by reference." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @mdsimmo You are returning a reference to a function-local variable. That variable _dies_ at the end of the function, so accessing the reference is Undefined Behavior.